# Optimize LINQ EF. Using where instead of joins?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I've written such query:

```
using (var _db = new LuxedecorContext())
            {
                var items = (from navItem in _db.NavItems
                             join dealItem in _db.Deal_Items
                             on navItem.ItemWebCode equals dealItem.ItemWebCode
                             join mainCategory in _db.Web_MainCategory
                             on new { A = navItem.Website, B = navItem.MainCategory }
                             equals new { A = mainCategory.Website, B = mainCategory.Code }
                             join subCategory in _db.Web_SubCategory
                             on new { A = navItem.Website, B = navItem.MainCategory, C = navItem.SubCategory }
                             equals new { A = subCategory.Website, B = subCategory.CodeMain, C = subCategory.Code }
                             select new
                             {
                                 SalePrice = navItem.SalePrice,
                                 Vendor = navItem.Vendor,
                                 Promo = navItem.Promo,
                                 Description = navItem.Description,
                                 FreightMax = navItem.FreightMax,
                                 ItemImage = navItem.ItemImage,
                                 ItemImage2 = navItem.ItemImage2,
                                 StrikedPrice = (navItem.RetailPrice ?? 0) * (1 - (navItem.PercentOff ?? 0) / 100) / (1 - navItem.PercentOffShow / 100),
                                 ItemId = navItem.ItemID,    
                                 StockQty = navItem.StockQty,
                                 SeoURL = navItem.SeoURL,                                
                                 DealSequence = dealItem.Sequence,
                                 DealId = dealItem.DealID,
                                 Website = navItem.Website
                             }).Where(x => x.SeoURL != string.Empty && x.DealId == dealId).GroupBy(x=>x.ItemId).Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault());


                if(onlyAvalaibleItems)
                    items = items.Where(x => x.StockQty != "0");

                switch(sort)
                {
                    case "PriceAsc":
                        items = items.OrderBy(x => x.SalePrice);
                        break;
                    case "PriceDesc":
                        items = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.SalePrice);
                        break;
                    case "DescriptionAsc":
                        items = items.OrderBy(x => x.Description.Replace(x.Vendor, "").Trim());
                        break;
                    case "DescriptionDesc":
                        items = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Description.Replace(x.Vendor, "").Trim());
                        break;
                    default:
                        items = items.OrderBy(x=>x.DealSequence);
                        break;
                }

                return await items.Select(x => new ProductCollectionItem
                {
                    SalePrice = x.SalePrice,
                    Vendor = x.Vendor,
                    Promo = x.Promo,
                    Description = x.Description,
                    FreightMax = x.FreightMax,
                    ItemImage = x.ItemImage,
                    ItemImage2 = x.ItemImage2,
                    StrikedPrice = x.StrikedPrice ?? 0
                }).ToListAsync();
            }
```

This is SQL, which I've got:

```
SELECT 
[Project4].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project4].[SalePrice] AS [SalePrice], 
[Project4].[Vendor] AS [Vendor], 
[Project4].[Promo] AS [Promo], 
[Project4].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Project4].[FreightMax] AS [FreightMax], 
[Project4].[ItemImage] AS [ItemImage], 
[Project4].[ItemImage2] AS [ItemImage2], 
[Project4].[C2] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Limit1].[C1] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as decimal(18)) ELSE [Limit1].[C1] END AS [C2], 
    [Limit1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Limit1].[SalePrice] AS [SalePrice], 
    [Limit1].[ItemImage] AS [ItemImage], 
    [Limit1].[ItemImage2] AS [ItemImage2], 
    [Limit1].[Vendor] AS [Vendor], 
    [Limit1].[Promo] AS [Promo], 
    [Limit1].[FreightMax] AS [FreightMax], 
    [Limit1].[Sequence] AS [Sequence]
    FROM   (SELECT 
        @p__linq__0 AS [p__linq__0], 
        @p__linq__1 AS [p__linq__1], 
        [Distinct1].[ItemID] AS [ItemID]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent1].[ItemID] AS [ItemID]
            FROM    [dbo].[NavItems] AS [Extent1]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Deal_Items] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ItemWebCode] = [Extent2].[ItemWebCode]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Web_MainCategory] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent1].[Website] = [Extent3].[Website]) AND ([Extent1].[MainCategory] = [Extent3].[Code])
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Web_SubCategory] AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent1].[Website] = [Extent4].[Website]) AND ([Extent1].[MainCategory] = [Extent4].[CodeMain]) AND ([Extent1].[SubCategory] = [Extent4].[Code])
            WHERE ( NOT (([Extent1].[SeoURL] = @p__linq__0) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[SeoURL] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN (@p__linq__0 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) AND ([Extent2].[DealID] = @p__linq__1)
        )  AS [Distinct1] ) AS [Project2]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent5].[Description] AS [Description], 
        [Extent5].[SalePrice] AS [SalePrice], 
        [Extent5].[ItemImage] AS [ItemImage], 
        [Extent5].[ItemImage2] AS [ItemImage2], 
        [Extent5].[Vendor] AS [Vendor], 
        [Extent5].[Promo] AS [Promo], 
        [Extent5].[FreightMax] AS [FreightMax], 
        [Extent6].[Sequence] AS [Sequence], 
        ((CASE WHEN ([Extent5].[RetailPrice] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as decimal(18)) ELSE [Extent5].[RetailPrice] END) * (cast(1 as decimal(18)) - ((CASE WHEN ([Extent5].[PercentOff] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as decimal(18)) ELSE [Extent5].[PercentOff] END) / cast(100 as decimal(18))))) / (cast(1 as decimal(18)) - ([Extent5].[PercentOffShow] / cast(100 as decimal(18)))) AS [C1]
        FROM    [dbo].[NavItems] AS [Extent5]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Deal_Items] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent5].[ItemWebCode] = [Extent6].[ItemWebCode]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Web_MainCategory] AS [Extent7] ON ([Extent5].[Website] = [Extent7].[Website]) AND ([Extent5].[MainCategory] = [Extent7].[Code])
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Web_SubCategory] AS [Extent8] ON ([Extent5].[Website] = [Extent8].[Website]) AND ([Extent5].[MainCategory] = [Extent8].[CodeMain]) AND ([Extent5].[SubCategory] = [Extent8].[Code])
        WHERE ( NOT (([Extent5].[SeoURL] = @p__linq__0) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent5].[SeoURL] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN (@p__linq__0 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) AND ([Extent6].[DealID] = @p__linq__1) AND ([Project2].[ItemID] = [Extent5].[ItemID]) ) AS [Limit1]
)  AS [Project4]
ORDER BY [Project4].[Sequence] ASC
```

There is no any relation in the old DB. I'm using most of joins just to cut data which I don't need. I wonder: is this a good way? How can I optimize my query?

Comment: Post the actual execution, current performance and perf goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always prefer not to use joins for filtering purposes. For two reasons:

- Joins may multiply the results (if the joined table is in a 1:n association), so you have to make the results distinct. This may be a compelling reason performance-wise.
- `Join` *conveys* that you want to extend the result set by fields from the joined table. `Any`, on the other hand, (or `EXISTS` in SQL) exactly conveys what you want: filtering. In other words: use the method that makes your code self-explanatory.

If you only have joins with 1..n-1 associations (which I assume), only the second reason counts, because performance shouldn't differ much. For me the second reason is compelling enough though.

Side note: even though the database doesn't have hard foreign key, I'd strongly recommend you do define associations (navigation properties) in the EF model. If you do that you can use code like

```
from navItem in _db.NavItems
where navItem.DealItem != null
```

Or pull the (pseudo) foreign keys into the class model as properties, so you can do

```
from navItem in _db.NavItems
where navItem.ItemWebCode.HasValue
```